# Getting ready to buy second GPU for my Aurora R5 to use for Blender

Tags: rendering, video

Okay, getting ready to drop the hammer on this.

So, if I get a second NVIDIA, I understand NOT to connect them via SLI conection.  Now, I have two monitors currently connected to my one GPU (via HDMIs). For best performance, do I keep both monitors plugged into the one GPU, or should I plug my second monitor into the second GPU?

Thanks!

Comment: Test and report back.

Comment: I think nvidia control panel handles that.